# Table object is not null here i found this error when i insert form data in the Database Student is my model

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

[image]I Don't Understand Why i Got this Error

Comment: You have a `MVC_CURD.Controllers.Student` instance, but you expect a `MVC_CURD.Models.Student` instance instead. Maybe your `using` statements are wrong or you need to specify the full namespace for the class you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

There are two classes called `Student` in you project, one for the ctrl/service layer and one for the db layer. This is quite common.

In your method you need to translate one type into the other type. For example:

```
var dbStudent = new MVC_CURD.Models.Student(...);

_Db.tbl_Student.Add(dbStudent);
```